# URDF vs SDF benifits?

Tags: ros2, urdf, turtlebot3, sdf

Turtlebo3_waffle and Turtlebot3_burger uses SDF for simulation in Gazebo and URDF for publishing TF  and visualizing in RVIZ. Is there any particular reason for doing so?

Answer (score 0):

ROS and Gazebo are two independent entities, developed for two very different purposes. ROS needs to know information about the robot, *i.e.*, how many links and joints there are, how they are connected, what are the kinematic and dynamic properties of each of them, and so on. For this purpose, the URDF (Universal Robot Description Format) is the best candidate. It describes a robot, how it looks like, its properties, limits of actuation, and so on.

On the other hand, Gazebo, which is a Physics simulator, needs to know much more information about not only the robot, but also the world that the robot is interacting with - what is the direction and magnitude of the gravitational force, what is the viscosity of the fluid that the robot is in *(very useful for underwater simulations)*, is there any sort of lighting/wind that might affect the agents in a simulation *(if you are trying to simulate a trash-picking robot, and you want to test if it can still pick trash during a storm, for example)*, and so on.

Note that Gazebo has a way of ingesting an URDF file, so if you are developing a robot (and simulation is only a part of development of the robot), I'd strongly advise to use URDF + xacro. In case you are only performing simulations in Gazebo, and you'd like to have a model of the robot, but the actual specifics of the robot do not concern you that much, you should proceed with SDF.

I'll point you towards some useful resources for further exploration:

- [URDF and sdf : When to use which](https://get-help.theconstruct.ai/t/urdf-and-sdf-whan-to-use-which/11556)
- [ROS Notes: URDF vs. Gazebo SDF](https://newscrewdriver.com/2018/07/31/ros-notes-urdf-vs-gazebo-sdf/)
- [SDF vs URDF what should one use](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/25286/sdf-vs-urdf-what-should-one-use)